# PLSQL procedure parameters in C#

Tags: c#, oracle

Our Oracle (11.2.0.4) db has a package XXXX, and I need to call one of its functions:

```
function GET_CLOB(
   P_TYPE OUT varchar2,
   P_MSG  OUT varchar2,
   P_BODY OUT clob
 ) return pls_integer;
```

I try to call it using following code in C#:

```
var cm = con.CreateCommand();
cm.CommandText = "Z$XXX.GET_CLOB";
cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cm.BindByName = true;
cm.Parameters.Add("Return_Value", OracleDbType.Int16,
                   ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
cm.Parameters.Add("P_TYPE", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 128).Value = "ForExDealRcvRq";
cm.Parameters.Add("P_MSG", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 128, 
                  ParameterDirection.Output);
cm.Parameters.Add("P_BODY", OracleDbType.Clob, ParameterDirection.Output);
cm.ExecuteScalar();
```

When there is no data to retrieve from DB, code is executed ok and I get return value, meaning underlying table is empty. But when there is data to be retrieved, I get following errors:

```
ORA-01017: Invalid Username/Password
ORA-06512:   "IBS.RTL", line 6505
ORA-06512:   "IBS.RTL", line 6515
ORA-06512:   "IBS.Z#aaaa", line 465
ORA-06512:   "IBS.Z$bbbb", line 71
ORA-06512:   "IBS.Z$bbbb", line 121
ORA-06512:   "IBS.Z$XXXX", line 433
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: : character string buffer too small
ORA-06512:   line 1
```

I have tried to play with parameter types and sizes, but can't do anything. Any advices where to look?

Comment: You should probably start with eliminating `Invalid Username/Password` error first...

Comment: I can execute that function from dbmanager (Embarcadero if it matters) from the same machine with same login/password without errors.

Comment: can we have a look to full code?

Comment: Increase the string buffer and try again (PL/SQL: : character string buffer too small)

Comment: I don't have access to procedure code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should set size for needed paramerters, because this error **ORA-06502: PL/SQL: : character string buffer too small** can be cause by you don't put the parameter size.

From your code, I noticed that you didn't set size for parameter **"P_MSG"**, just set parameter value to be 128.

And this is the overload you're using to add **"P_MSG"** parameter.

```
Add(string name, OracleDbType dbType, object val, ParameterDirection dir)
```

This method adds an OracleParameter object to the collection using the supplied name, database type, parameter value, and direction.

Then I think you should code such this sample instead

```
var oParam = New OracleParameter("P_MSG", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
oParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
oParam.Size = 128;
cm.Parameters.Add(oParam);
```

Comment: Yep, I've found it out too. Have to make an OracleParameter variable and "manually" set attributes to make it work.